# Python codes to exe using py2exe , not working after successfully convert

Tags: python-3.x, exe, py2exe

I am using the below codes to covert to exe format to ensure to do my upcoming project. I successfully converted to .exe , but when i click it , i am not seeing the tkinter window,i am seeing block cmd window opening and closing , not erros as well.

I am using 3.4 python

print1.py

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title("Automated Configuration Manager")
```

setup1.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['Print1.py'],
    options = {
          'py2exe': {
              'packages': ['tkinter']
              }
          }
    )
```

i am running below commands in python 34 path to covert to exe and i am getting the folder dist with exe file

```
C:\python34\python setup1.py install  (not this one now)

C:\python34\python setup1.py py2exe  (only this lines)
```

(for this command i am getting the exe, when i run the exe from same path, but not able to see tkinter window, no erros)

any help here, i am having my project file in codes, which using 
tkinter, csv, urrlib3, and more.

once above code tested, i am going to covert my complete codes

**Process of covert:**

I am posting the process, still i am not getting tkinter window, but program running fine

```
C:\windows\system32>cd C:\Python34

C:\Python34>python setup1.py py2exe
running py2exe

  6 missing Modules
  ------------------
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? resource                            imported from test.support
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
? win32evtlog                         imported from logging.handlers
? win32evtlogutil                     imported from logging.handlers
Building 'dist\Print1.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\windows\system32\python34.dll to dist
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd to dist\_multiprocessing.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd to dist\_tkinter.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_testcapi.pyd to dist\_testcapi.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy DLL C:\Python34\DLLs\tcl86t.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Python34\DLLs\tk86t.dll to dist\

C:\Python34>cd dist
C:\Python34\dist>print1.exe
C:\Python34\dist>
```

(above console showing program running fine, but no window display)

(6 missing Modules please advise on this)

Comment: open up a console, navigate to your main python module(i'm assuming it's the display.py one) in the folder dist and run it with cli `python display.py`. What do you see in the console?

Comment: It is also successfully completing the execution and back to path. but  no tkinter window opening